# Pycharm: Code documentation differs between seemingly equal installations

Tags: python, pycharm, psycopg2, code-documentation

A colleague of mine and I edit code from the same repository. Its a Python application using `psycopg2` as a database driver to speak to PostgreSQL clusters. We are both decently new at this, so good documentation and doc support by the IDE is paramount to prevent mistakes.

To have autocompletion of methods, classes, functions and the likes the IDE needs to know what type of objects the variables are. As sometimes it is difficult for the IDE to determine this itself, you can usually use annotations of the syntax

```
myvar = functioncall() #  type: <Class/Data type>
```

This defines myvar as the type given at the end of the line, and enables the IDE to autocomplete methods in `myvar` from the class/data type given.

In the following line, Pycharm could not determine the type of value that the methods returns:

```
with psycopg2.connect(dsn) as conn:
```

I took a look into the definition of `psycopg2.connect()` using Ctrl+q, and I got this printout:

```
psycopg2
def connect(dsn: Any = None,
            connection_factory: Any = None,
            cursor_factory: Any = None,
            **kwargs: Any) -> None
```

Plus the whole documentation about the parameters, and ending with the note:

```
< Python 3.9 (venv39selected) >
```

The Python version we both use is 3.9, and `venv39selected` is the name of the venv that I use.

So I could see why the IDE could not determine the data type of the return value of `connect`, it doesn't document a return type.

However, after complaining to my colleague about the problem, he showed me his Ctrl+q popup, and in that, the following is printed:

```
psycopg2
def connect(dsn: Any | None = ...,
            connection_factory: Any | None = ...,
            cursor_factory: Any | None = ...,
            **kwargs: Any) -> connection | connection
```

So he seems to have a different popup than me, one that allows his IDE to find the right return type for the variable. In all program versions, our systems and installations are the same. Python 3.9 on Windows, the same packages inside the venv, psycopg2 in version 2.9.3.

However, and that is the most interesting part: You can use Ctrl+mouseclick to enter any method/function definition. Entering the function definition of the `connect` method shows the same exact code for both our IDEs, and both are without the return type!

So the documentation shown in the Ctrl+q popup must come from somewhere else than from parsing the code shown using Ctrl+click. But from where? Where is that configured?

Comment: `PyCharm` versions the same?

Comment: Potentially related to [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31565) (with no help)

Comment: Thank you @nanotek that link really helped.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, the Pycharm version is exactly the same, we updated both version at the same time using the online updater.